# Yii2 SwiftMailer .eml files created but with wrong names & file_put_contents Permission denied

Tags: yii2, swiftmailer

The problem is when I'm trying to "send" the email it's failing with the message

> file_put_contents(/some/path//frontend/runtime/debug/mail/20180413-165142-0679-0633.eml):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied

The file is being created but with a slightly different name, for example `20180413-165142-0666-8857.eml` (I can see it by time). I have no idea what is going on. Any suggestions?

Config file is simple:

common/main-local.php

```
        'mailer' => [
           'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
           'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
           // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
           // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
           // for the mailer to send real emails.
           'useFileTransport' => true,
        ],
```

And sending by this:

```
Yii::$app->mailer->compose('order', ['order' => $this])
        ->setTo(Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'])
        ->setFrom(Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'])
        ->setSubject('New order #' . $this->id)
        ->send();
```

And `'adminEmail' => 'admin@example.com',`

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: did you added `755` permission  on `runtime` folder?

Comment: hello. i even added 777 permission. but you see files were created! so, it's not permission problem.